# Align boxed equation to the left margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, box

I am attempting to left align a boxed equation but I failed.  Can you help me align this boxed equation to the left margin:?  Thank you!

[image]

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\boxed{
\begin{aligned}
\omega_{r}= & \omega_{m}\sqrt{1-2\zeta^{2}}\\
\text{if} \quad & \zeta<0.707
\end{aligned}}
\end{flalign*}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution with the `fleqn`  environment from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
\boxed{ \begin{aligned}
\omega_{r}={} & \omega_{m}\sqrt{1-2\zeta^{2}}\\
\text{if} \quad & \zeta<0.707
\end{aligned} }
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just add some dummy alignment points, to make `flalign` do its work on expanding spaces between columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{flalign*}
\boxed{
\begin{aligned}
\omega_{r}= & \omega_{m}\sqrt{1-2\zeta^{2}}\\
\text{if} \quad & \zeta<0.707
\end{aligned}}&&&
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I reduced the number of packages to the bare minimum needed (except for `lipsum` that provides the mock text).

[image]